# requestIDFA / App Tracking permission iOS 14 - How to set it to show ads after prompt?

Tags: ios, objective-c

On my app I am asking this straight after it launches for the first time

```
- (void)requestIDFA {
    
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
            [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
                         break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                       
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                        
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
      
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                        break;
                }
            }];
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }        
}
```

My code to load the ad banner is

```
- (void)addGoogleMobileAds {
    
    if(areAdsRemoved){
        
        NSLog(@"Remove Ads IAP Purchased");
        
    }else{
    
    [IronSource setBannerDelegate:self];
    [IronSource loadBannerWithViewController:self size:ISBannerSize_SMART];
   
}
```

But I can't see where to use `[self addGoogleMobileAds];` I don't want them to load BEFORE the user has chosen their option for IDFA request.

And for those no using 14.5 or higher, I need to ensure `[self addGoogleMobileAds];` loads for them too.

Edit -

So I can use it like this - ? However if I use it like below, the ads do not appear until the app is closed and re-opened, then it works as expected.

```
- (void)requestIDFA {

    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
            [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            [self addGoogleMobileAds];
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
                         break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            [self addGoogleMobileAds];
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            [self addGoogleMobileAds];
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            [self addGoogleMobileAds];

                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                        break;
                }
            }];
        } else {
        [self addGoogleMobileAds];
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }        
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the ad frameworks will work for you even if users deny tracking; it's just that they won't be personalized. If you're trying to defer the setup by waiting for user consent, then just handle their response in the callback block.

Comment: @Vym I have updated my question - so the last part I can use ?

Comment: @user1695971 have you checked that [self addGoogleMobileAds]; is called after IDFA is given?... If yes then, can you specify that whats happening after call [self addGoogleMobileAds];?